# Scripting map production in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

I'm trying to automate my production of maps with GRASS.

What I want to do can be described in fairly generic terms: I have two layers (one vector, one raster), which will be identical in every map. I have one layer (a raster heat-map) that will come from a different file for every map. I can write a shell or Python script (Mac OS X) to loop some GRASS command over all the heat-map files in a directory, but I am not sufficiently competent with GRASS to have figured out how to handle that end of the process.

Could someone give me an example of GRASS command-line code that will take a few files as inputs and produce a single image file as output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that, you need;

1. to import the files (shapefiles, raster) in GRASS GIS
2. use the adequate modules

You can use Bash or Python from:

- the Command Console or the Python Shell of the Layer manager

[image]

- the GRASS shell (Python here, but you can also use [R](http://www.r-project.org/))

[image]

- the Mac shell  (Python, here, but you can also use [R](http://www.r-project.org/))

[image]

To use bash scripts, see [Shell Scripting](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Shell_scripting)  or [On scripting GRASS GIS: Building location-independent command line tools](http://geoinformatics.fsv.cvut.cz/gwiki/On_scripting_GRASS_GIS:_Building_location-independent_command_line_tools)
To use Python, see [GRASS and Python](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python) or [Python Scripts For GRASS GIS](http://code.google.com/p/postgis-grass-r-py/wiki/0003_01_PythonForGrassGis)

I will develop Python that I know best.

**Python with grass module**

In Python, you simply access the GRASS functions as:

```
debligne =grass.read_command("v.to.db", flags="p", map="testgrass", type="line", option="start", units="meters" , quiet=True)
```

If you want to import all the tif files in a directory, see , for example, [Python: script to import multiple LANDSAT images to Grass GIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073855/python-script-to-import-multiple-landsat-images-to-grass-gis)

```py
for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
    # Iterate through the files 
    for raster in filenames:
          # If the suffix is '.TIF', process
          if raster.upper().endswith('.tif'):
                # full path to your file
                full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, tif_file)
                # GRASS commands
                grass.message('Importing %s -> %s@%s...' % (full_path, tif_file, dirpath))
                grass.run_command('r.in.gdal',flags = 'o',input = full_path, output = tif_file,quiet = True,overwrite = True)
```

See other example in the  above-mentioned references or in [Automatic 3D geological boreholes representation (automate v.extrude from a table ?): my solution in Python](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Automatic-3D-geological-boreholes-representation-automate-v-extrude-from-a-table-my-solution-in-Pythn-td4978801.html)  or [GRASS and the Python geospatial modules (Shapely, PySAL,...)](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASS-and-the-Python-geospatial-modules-Shapely-PySAL-td4985075.html)

**Python with osgeo module**

You can also use the osgeo (GDAL/OGR) Python module:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
# open grass vector layer
ds = ogr.Open('/Users/username/grassdata/geol/mymapset/vector/testgrass/head')
# vector layer  
layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
layer.GetName()
'testgrass'
 feat = layer.GetFeature(0) 
 # geometry
 geom = feat.GetGeometryRef() 
 geom.ExportToWkt() 
 'LINESTRING (186139.123704173340229 53082.654193976894021,188199.122798504744424 53467.758558732457459)'
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you're answered my question, but it'll take me just a little bit to work through what you've provided.